# How to GET private repositories using curl?

Tags: api, curl, github, get

I want to get a list of my private repositories from GitHub. In the GitHub REST API documentation it states that [the `visibility` as `private` can be supplied as parameter](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories). But I don't know how to do it.

I am able to get a list of my public repositories using the following command in command line

```
curl -u "username:password" -X GET https://mygithuburl.com/users/username/repos
```

How to supply the `visibility` parameter to `private` to get a list of only the private repos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [supply the parameters as regular query string arguments](https://developer.github.com/v3/#parameters):

> Many API methods take optional parameters. For `GET` requests, any parameters not specified as a segment in the path can be passed as an HTTP query string parameter:
>
> ```
> curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues?state=closed"
> ```
>
> In this example, the 'vmg' and 'redcarpet' values are provided for the `:owner` and `:repo` parameters in the path while `:state` is passed in the query string.

In your case:

```
curl \
    -u "username:password" \
    -X GET \
    https://mygithuburl.com/user/repos?visibility=private
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It did not work correctly but did point me to the right documentation. What did not work for me was the parameter visibility with the given url. It always gave me an empty list. In the documentation it is mentioned that the visibility parameters is applicable for `GET user/repos` and not for `GET /users/:username/repos`. So if I change my URL to to `https://mygithuburl.com/user/repos?visibility=private`, Then I get the list of repos which are private and I have access to. If you could change the url in your solution, then I would accept that as an answer.